# TensorFlow Lite PoseNet on Android crashes because of memory

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am trying to create an Android app that uses TensorFlow Lite PoseNet for human pose estimation.
The problem I have is that native memory slowly increases until it crashes.
Even if I run the [demo app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/posenet/android) it will crash on my S10 after about 20 minutes.
I tried profiling it and I don't think it is a leak because if I code it so that the interpreter takes breaks then garbage collection is able to keep up.

I would like to have it do estimations at a rate of about 15 per second which seems to do very well for a few minutes. Is there a way to tune it to run longer or is that unrealistic for running on a device such as a Samsung S10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a memory leak in the Android PoseNet demo app that is not noticeable unless you enable `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)`

The PosenetActivity.kt captureSession!!.setRepeatingRequest was using a backgroundHandler which was holding a reference that was preventing native memory from getting cleaned up. The callback and handler is not needed for setRepeatingRequest.
Changing this

```
      previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder!!.build()
      captureSession!!.setRepeatingRequest(
        previewRequest!!,
        captureCallback, backgroundHandler
      )
```

to

```
  previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder!!.build()
  captureSession!!.setRepeatingRequest(
    previewRequest!!,
    null, null
  )
```

fixes the memory leak.

Also, the demo app Posenet.kt is coded to use CPU which probably helps support a greater range of devices but switching it to GPU or NNAPI speeds things up significantly.

Comment: I created a pull request to fix the leak https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/pull/284